# DOMException when trying to play video via socket event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, html5-video

When trying to play video from a socket event, the browser throws a DOMException with no stacktrace. The stub responsible to do that is as below.

The state holds the value obtained from `document.querySelector('video')`

```
socket.on('PLAY', data => {
  const { video } = this.state;
  video.play(); // exception here
});
```

Exception: 
[image: DOMException]

I'm sure that `this.state.video` is referring to valid `<video>` tag. 
I've also tried using async await on the callback method, but that doesn't help.

Why would this happen? and why is there no stacktrace?

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Can you post the code on how you're sending the stream from your server? Also because you're sending it from your server, you probably need to modify the data..

Switch your browser also, try using Mozilla Firefox, I notice that will give better error responses..

Comment: @JD333 thanks, mozilla gave a better error log. Helped me understand the reason.